# Discrete Math Relations

Tags: discrete-mathematics, relations

could you please help me in that question?

Let N[x] be the set of all polynomials with coefficients in N. Prove that N[x] is countably infinite.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Your question is phrased as an isolated problem, without any further information or context. This does not match [many users' quality standards](http://goo.gl/mLWc8), so it may attract downvotes, or closed. To prevent that, please [edit] the question. [This](http://goo.gl/PlJyVQ) will help you recognise and resolve the issues. Concretely: please provide context, and include your work and thoughts on the problem. These changes can help in formulating more appropriate answers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are looking for a bijection from $N[x]$ to $N$.

Consider the mapping $\pi$ which takes 1 to the smallest prime, 2 to the second smallest prime, and so on.

Show that $\pi$ is a bijection from the set N to the set of primes $\Pi$.

Take a polynomial $p\in N[x]$, $p = \sum a_{i}x^{i}$.

Consider the mapping $f$ defined so that:

$$f(p) = f(\sum a_{i}x^{i}) = \prod \pi(i)^{a_{i}}.$$

This is a bijection from $N$ to N \ {1} by the existence of a unique prime factorization for all integers bigger than 1.

It should be clear now, but to get a perfect bijection consider $g(n) = n - 1$.

Then $$g(f(p))= g(f(\sum a_{i}x^{i})) = \prod \pi(i)^{a_{i}} -1$$

is a bijection from $N[x]$ to $N$.